# Best Way to write large data over network stream of TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

We have a requirement to upload large firmware files to printers to upgrade the firmware of the device. The printer device is in the same network as my server, and the size of firmware that we are trying to upload is approximately to 200 - 500 MB. The approach that we have chosen is to load the firmware (.bin file) into Memory stream and write it in chunks over the network using `TcpClient`.

Based on the response from the network stream, we are displaying the status of firmware upgrade to the client. Following is the code snippet that we have used for firmware upgrade. I want to know if it is the best approach, as wrong one may harm the device.

**EDIT:**

```
class MyClass
{
    int port = 9100;
    string _deviceip;
    byte[] m_ReadBuffer = null;
    TcpClient _tcpclient;
    NetworkStream m_NetworkStream;
    static string CRLF = "\r\n";

    public event EventHandler<DeviceStatus> onReceiveUpdate;

    public async Task<bool> UploadFirmware(Stream _stream)
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            _tcpclient = new TcpClient();
            _tcpclient.Connect(_deviceip, port);

            _stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            m_NetworkStream = _tcpclient.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            m_ReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int readcount = 0;
            m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_ReadBuffer, 0, m_ReadBuffer.Length,
                                     new AsyncCallback(EndReceive), null);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while ((readcount = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    m_NetworkStream.Write(buffer, 0, readcount);
                    m_NetworkStream.Flush();
                }
            });
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            upgradeStatus = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

     private void EndReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
     {
         try
         {
             int nBytes;
             nBytes = m_NetworkStream.EndRead(ar);
             if (nBytes > 0)
             {
                 string res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_ReadBuffer, 0, nBytes);
                 DeviceStatus status = new DeviceStatus();

                 string[] readlines = res.Split(new string[] { CRLF }, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                 foreach (string readline in readlines)
                 {
                     if (readline.StartsWith("CODE"))
                     {
                         //read readline string here
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }

            if (m_NetworkStream.CanRead)
            {
                do
                {
                    m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_ReadBuffer, 0, m_ReadBuffer.Length, new 
                                           AsyncCallback(EndReceive), null);
                } while (m_NetworkStream.DataAvailable);
            }
         }
         catch (ObjectDisposedException ods)
         {
             return;
         }
         catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
         {
         }
     }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is basically fine with a few issues:

1. `m_NetworkStream.Flush();` AFAIK this does nothing. If it did something it would harm throughput. So delete that.
2. `_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` seeking is the callers concern, remove that. This is a layering violation.
3. Use bigger bigger buffers. Determine the right size experimentally. I usually start at 64KB for bulk transfers. This makes the IOs less chatty.
4. Turn on nagling which helps with bulk transfers because it saves you from spurious small packets.
5. You can replace the entire read-write-loop with `Stream.Copy`.
6. The way you report exceptions to the callers hides a lot of information. Just let the exception bubble out. Don't return a bool.
7. Use `using` for all resource to ensure they are cleaned up in the error case.
8. `nBytes = m_NetworkStream.EndRead(ar);` here, you assume that a single read will return all data that will be coming. You might receive just the first byte, though. Probably, you should use `StreamReader.ReadLine` in a loop until you know you are done.
9. `catch (System.IO.IOException ex) { }` What is that about? If firmware updates are such a critical thing suppressing errors appears very dangerous. How else can you find out about bugs?
10. I would convert the reading code to use `await`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing such a detailed analysis. However, I am confused in implementing 8th point. Do you mean I should use a loop inside my EndReceive method? I will really appreciate if you elaborate this point.

Comment: I was thinking more like this: `Task.Run(() => { while(true) var line = myStreamReader.ReadLine(); if (IsEnd(line)) break; else ProcessLine(line); });`. That's the idea, please see if you can make this work for you. You can delete all the Begin/End garbage. The APM pattern is obsolete and difficult to handle.

Comment: `IsEnd` could be `return line == null || line.StartsWith("CODE")` if I understand your intention correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to fit the logic mentioned by you in my code and verify if it really works.

Answer (score -2):

As the maximum length for a TcpPacket is 65535 (2^16-1), if you send any packet breaching this lenght it will be truncated. If I were you, I think the best way of sending large packets, is setting a Header of every packet and enumerating them. For example:
C->S ; `[P1] <content>`
and then the same structure, just plus 1 `[P2] <content>`
To do so, just use few substrings to truncate the data and sending them.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sending it at once. Maybe you didn't notice, I am sending data in chunks in while loop.

Comment: TCP does not expose packet semantics. It's a continuous stream of bytes and applications cannot do anything wrong by sending certain packets because apps are not sending packets at all.